# Terraform: order of creating array of resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have two ec2 instances defined in terraform using the `count` method.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = "2"
  ami = "ami-2d39803a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "example-${count.index}"
  }
}
```

How can I enforce that they are launched one after the other? e.g. the second instance should be created when the first one finishes.

**Attempt 1:**

`depends_on = [aws_instance.example[0]]`

result:

> Error: aws_instance.example: resource depends on non-existent resource 'aws_instance.example[0]'

**Attempt 2:**

```
tags {
  Name = "example-${count.index}"
  Active = "${count.index == "1" ? "${aws_instance.example.1.arn}" : "this"}"
}
```

result:

> Error: aws_instance.example[0]: aws_instance.example[0]: self reference not allowed: "aws_instance.example.0.arn"

Which leads me to believe the interpolation is calculated after the instance configurations are complete thus it doesn't see that there isn't in fact a circular dependency.

**Any ideas?**

Thanks

Comment: Why do they need to be launched in a specific order instead of all at once?

Comment: Trying to implement blue-green deployment

Comment: There's not enough information here about what you're fully trying to achieve but it doesn't look the right way to do this. If you were happy to hardcode them into separate groups of resources you could easily set the second group to depend on the first one but this is kinda ugly and I feel like you'd be better off using other patterns for Terraform and blue/green such as ASGs with `create_before_destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `terraform apply -parallelism=1` to limit the number of concurrent operations to 1 at a time.

Comment: I want to be able to determine which one gets launched first though